# View older "What's new" for Android apps

Tags: google-play-store

Play Store shows "What's New" for the latest version of an app. Is there a way to see it for older versions?

Comment: some publishers append their new changes over older existing changelogs, while others just replace it for every new version. Play Store probably won't let you see older changelogs but you can still visit the app's homepage.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am asking precisely because of a publisher which doesn't provide a changelog at their homepage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Changelog Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cypressworks.changelogviewer&hl=en) app will start building a history of app changes from the date it's installed.

Comment: That app is no longer available.